# Jenkins - Bitbucket pull request strategy for merging

Tags: git, jenkins, merge, webhooks, pull-request

I am trying to create a flow between Git and Jenkins for pull request strategy. So i have two repositories on my Bitbucket: origin and my repo. The origin is the main repo and my repo is a forked from the first one. Now, i want when a pull request is open from my fork to the main repo, a job to be triggered on the Jenkins. The started job will run some unit tests on the the new source code from the pull request.  If the unit tests are good after the new changes, the pull request will be merged. I managed to trigger the build with parameters but i dont know how to run job on pull request code. I mean how can i run the Jenkins job on my repo from where i am trying to merge the code in the main repo?

Comment: are you on bitbucket cloud or server?

Comment: can you show what you've tried up to now?

Answer (score 0):

For triggering a jenkins job when you merge a pull request you can use "Bitbucket Plugin" . Install this on your jenkins server. 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-plugin

And then add your jenkins server URL to your repository settings -> Webhook